# My textviews width is not static in my custom list view

Tags: android, android-layout

My textviews width is not static in my custom list view i need the size of my textview to be standard but its not working

my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/menuitemsgradient" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgChkOut"
            android:layout_width="60px"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_delete" >
                </ImageView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="Name: "
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolorWhite" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:text="xdf "
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="Price: "
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolorWhite" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="Quantity: "
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolorWhite" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtQty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/textcolorWhite"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorBlack" >
                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/text_button_bg"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="+" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/text_button_bg"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="-" >
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="Total: "
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolorWhite" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

http://imageshare.web.id/viewer.php?file=4jlqbt6ge3jj5kq0omht.png

The quantity row' tetxview is working weird i dont know why ... pls help me thanks in advance

Comment: Hi dinu can I know why you are using android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: to make it align properly to all screen sizes

Comment: give that weight property  to TableRow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on each TableRow ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create a small layout it will give you idea to create your layout. Maybe helpful for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price : "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:singleLine="true" android:gravity="right"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quantity : "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Button" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```